# Why is include cuda_runtime.h marked red in vscode despite cuda toolkit being installed properly?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, cuda

I have a c - cuda project. It has a main.c file and a deviceFunctions.cu file.
Visual Studio Code is used to work on the project also this extension: `ms-vscode.cpptools` is installed to get Code completion and error checking etc.

The helper.h file has all the include Statements that are needed in the device and host code. Then the header is included in both those files.
This statement: `#include <cuda_runtime.h>` is needed to run cuda code but its marked red. Why is that despite proper cuda toolkit installation and no errors when running the code? Also the code completion by the extension is not working well too.

The code is compiled using these commands:

```bash
#Compile Cuda object file:                                                                                                                                                              
nvcc -O3 -c -g -o target.o -arch=sm_75 deviceFunctions.cu                                                                                                                          
#Device Link (what exactly is meant by this idk)                                                                                                  
nvcc -O3 -g -o dlink.o -arch=sm_75 -dlink target.o                                                                                                                  
#Compile C code
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -g -o main main.c -I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include -L/usr/local/cuda-12.3/lib64 -lcudadevrt -lm -lrt                                                                                                                                                                                  
#Final Link                                                                                                                                                                  
gcc -g -o compute_output main dlink.o target.o -I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include -L/usr/local/cuda-12.3/lib64 -lcudadevrt -lcudart -lm -lrt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that the extension needs information about how the code is compiled to understand everything, like the include statements. For example the cuda toolkit library is included in the compile commands but the extension needs that information aswell.

For that purpose you need to add a "compile_commands.json" file to the root directory of your project. In this case that file can't be auto generated. If you use Cmake to build the project it can be. In this case however the file should look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "directory": "/path/to/project",
    "command": "nvcc -O3 -c -g -o target.o --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 deviceFunctions.cu",
    "file": "cudafunction.cu"
  },
  {
    "directory": "/path/to/project",
    "command": "nvcc -O3 -g -o dlink.o --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 -dlink target.o",
    "file": "dlink.o"
  },
  {
    "directory": "/path/to/project",
    "command": "gcc -std=gnu99 -c -g -o main main.c -I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include -L/usr/local/cuda-12.3/lib64 -lcudadevrt -lcublas -lcublasLt -lcudart -lm -lrt",
    "file": "main.c"
  },
  {
    "directory": "/path/to/project",
    "command": "gcc -g -o compute_output main dlink.o target.o -I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include -L/usr/local/cuda-12.3/lib64 -lcudadevrt -lcublas -lcublasLt -lcudart -lm -lrt",
    "file": "compute_output"
  }
]
```

If this file is correct as well as the cuda toolkit installation the extension will not mark the include statement as red anymore and the code completion will work as well with the device code and the host code.

Answer (score -1):

I've ran into the same issue today after reinstalling my CUDA toolkit. It did not happen before despite the lack of a "compile_commands.json" file. My project compiles and runs fine, so the installation is probably correct. However, VScode seems unable to recognize it. I have updated my "c_cpp_properties.json" file to explicitly include the compiler and library paths:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/cuda-12.3/lib64",
            "/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

I have also manually created a "compile_commands.json" file with the following contents:

```
[
{
    "directory": "~/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/src/",
    "command": "nvcc gompper_memb.cu -o gmemb -lcublas -lcusolver",
    "file": "gompper_memb.cu"
}
```

]

Despite this, VSCode does not recognize any basic header files nor cuda libraries (such as "cuda_runtime.h") and so does not recognise as correct nor provide support for any cuda code such as **global** function call configurations.

EDIT: the problem seems to be fixed by changing the compiler path in "c_cpp_properties.json" from the gcc path to the nvcc path. I do not understand how to add several compilers as needed for your original question, nor why the default-generated file has worked fine until now if it didn't have the compiler I'm using.

Comment: Your directory path has a space between cuda and codes. Also in your c_cpp_properties you give g++ as compiler but you compile with nvcc. Also I dont think you need to add -lcublas to the compile command.

Comment: It does have a space, and this "trivial" space formatting seems to work, since I fixed the issue. I do need to add -lcublas when compiling, or else the cublas API calls will cause weird runtime errors. I have changed gcc for nvcc since I posted, and it seems to fix the problem, but I still fail to understand why the default-generated file has worked correctly for months and only now caused problems.

Comment: I don't know why but the same happened to me. Only after reinstalling the cuda toolkit it showed the weird behavior. But I think after fixing the issue at least the cuda code completion works better for me than even before reinstalling. Also check your code with `compute-sanitizer ./executable` it might show memory leaks even if the function returns cuda success and the program runs through.

Comment: I dont use c_cpp_properties.json it is not required.